# Identifying the string in between two strings in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [retrieving the substring based on condition from a string in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100379/retrieving-the-substring-based-on-condition-from-a-string-in-iphone)

I am new to iphone.I am struck in some issue that is,I have one string which represents the source code of some website(http://www.audiotreasure.com/indexKJV.htm) in the xmlformat

please see the view source of the above website that view source is my present string right now

In the above string I want to search the strings in between the strings which starts with (href =") and ends with (.zip) then we get all the strings in between these two strings and after that i have to place all those strings into an array..

how it is possible if any body know this please explain this in step by step procedure and help me......

Answer (score 1):

Use a NSRegularExpression:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"href=\"(.*)\.zip\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:yourText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourText length])];

if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {

    NSString *substringForFirstMatch = [yourText substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
    NSLog(@"Extracted URL: %@",substringForFirstMatch);
}
```