# How to get the substrings in a string by using regular expressions

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [retrieving the substring based on condition from a string in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100379/retrieving-the-substring-based-on-condition-from-a-string-in-iphone)
>   [Identifying the string in between two strings in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102005/identifying-the-string-in-between-two-strings-in-iphone)

I am new to iphone. I have small doubt that is, I have a lot of strings(nearly 66) like in the format href="/mp3/KJV/21_Ecc/Ecc_KJV.zip" In a single string but the difference of all those is changing names in the place of Ecc but all are in same format.So,my request is to how to get the all strings which are started with (href=") and ends with (.zip) using regular expressions and how to write a regular expression for the above format string to identify all strings in that format.

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Hope this may help you. Thanks

NSString *param = nil;

NSString *objString=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"href=\"/mp3/KJV/21_Ecc/Ecc_KJV.zip\""];

```
NSRange start = [objString rangeOfString:@"href="];
if (start.location != NSNotFound)
{
    param = [objString substringFromIndex:start.location + start.length];
    NSRange end = [param rangeOfString:@".zip"];
    if (end.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        param = [objString substringToIndex:end.location];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Substring==%@",param);

//param now contains your value (or nil if not found)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *sourceString = ...// your string for search substrings

NSString *pattern = @"href=(.*?).zip";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];    
NSArray *results = [regex matchesInString:sourceString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [sourceString length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* result in results)
{
    NSString *resultString = [sourceString substringWithRange:result.range];
    NSLog(@"%@",resultString);
}
```